# How To Validate user input to match any string without characters like %, *, ? in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I Want To Validate user input to match any string without characters like %, *, ? using C++11
These Special Characters is illegal in my input

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop?

Comment: [Regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do that with regular expressions I guess, but there's a simpler way. You can use the [`std::string::find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) member function like so:

```
std::string input;
// ...
bool valid = (input.find_first_of("%*?") == std::string::npos);
```

Comment: @mos.acit: You're welcome. Please if this solves your problem consider marking the answer as accepted when you will be allowed :)

Comment: When I Build The Project I have this error :                     error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos" (?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2IB)

Comment: @mos.acit: This is a linker error, so there's something you are not linking in your project - I would say, the standard library

Comment: Can I use another thing instead of npos

Comment: @mos.acit: No, that is the right way of detecting if the characters was found. Please refer to the wiki page linked in the answer. I think you should try to solve your problem instead of finding a workaround